# Chrome 80 position sticky element only sticking the looks, not the DOM itself

Tags: css, google-chrome, sticky

I have this `td` element with sticky position:

```
tr td:last-child {
   position: sticky;
   left: 100px;
}
```

But this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the link doesn't get hovered when it is "actually" hovered, unless the mouse pointer is on it's original place (like when it's left is set to 0 or the position is not sticky). It's like that the `sticky` property only moves the "looks" of the element, not its content!

It was working in the older versions of chrome (78) But now it's not working. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug, It's fixed in in the latest version.